# CGContextSetFillColorWithColor not working on iphone 6 and 6 plus simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to draw some image and use following code. On my simulator (iphone 6 and 6 plus), it doesn't show any color and it become transparent. However, on my iPhone 5 device and iPhone 5 simulator, it can show color. May I know what happen? Have anyone tested/done on iPhone 6 and 6 plus device?

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.973 green:0.976 blue:0.976 alpha:1.000] CGColor]);
```

Edited: for more code

```
CGContextRef context;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake( [self width],
                                        [self height]));
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

switch (kind) {
    case PKNumberPadViewImageLeft:
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 6.0, [self height]);
        break;

    case PKNumberPadViewImageInner:
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, [self height]);
        break;

    case PKNumberPadViewImageRight:
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -6.0, [self height]);
        break;
}
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextClip(context);

//----

CGRect frame = CGPathGetBoundingBox(path);

//TODO: Ios 8 iph 6 and 6 plus not ok
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithRed:0.973 green:0.976 blue:0.976 alpha:1.000] CGColor]);

CGContextFillRect(context, frame);

CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
CFRelease(path);
```

Comment: What happens on the iPhone 5S simulator? Show more of the code to provide some context.

Comment: I have added more code. I haven't tested on iPhone 5s simulator but I tested on iPhone 5 device and simulator. Also , on iPhone 6 and 6 plus simulator (those 2 are not okay)

Comment: Try the 5S. If it has a problem like the 6 and 6+ then it is probably due to a 64-bit issue somewhere.

Comment: Yes. iPhone 5s simulator also not okay. How shall I do?